# Json: Add object to array

Tags: java, arrays, json

I am using javax.json library to use Json in Java. 
I am trying to add JsonObject in JsonArray, for example:

```
[
    { "some_stuff": "stuff" },
    { "some_stuff": "stuff" }
]
```

I need to add to this array next object with same keys as in example, but i have frozen at`array.add();`

```
JsonObject jsonObject = Json.createObjectBuilder()
    .add("some_stuff", "stuff")
        .build();

JsonArray array = jsonReader.readArray();
array.add(jsonObject); // UnsupportedOperationException
```

Comment: I don't think you will succeed in that unless you serialize the object you want to add. http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_serialization.htm

Comment: how do you initialize your Json Reader ?

Comment: @OzanTabak Yes. This is just example.

Comment: And I am using javax.json library.

Comment: javax.json is one of the worst JSON kits for Java.  There are about a dozen others.

Comment: So can i understand, that it is bugged?

Comment: The odd way you have to create JsonObject and JsonArray, for one.  You should apparently use `Json.createArrayBuilder()` to create your array.  (Other kits let you simply say `new JsonArray()`.)

Comment: Apparently, though, the javax.json JsonObject and JsonArray do inherit Map and List, so you can use Map/List put/add, rather than the arcane way they want you to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JsonArray is immutable so you cannot add ojects to it (hence the exception). From the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/json/JsonArray.html):

> JsonArray represents an immutable JSON array (an ordered sequence of zero or more values). It also provides an unmodifiable list view of the values in the array.

You need to use `JsonArrayBuilder` object. Here is at least one way to do that:

1. Create a `JsonArrayBuilder` object. (see the link to the docs for how)
2. Add each of the elements inside of your `JsonArray array =
   jsonReader.readArray();` object to the `JsonArrayBuilderObject`
3. Add your `JsonObject`.
4. Call `.build` on the `JsonArrayBuilder` to convert it to a `JsonArray` that will contain all of the elements.